# Not able to add queries to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am currently showing users who have registered on to my app in the fragment.I am trying to implement queries onto firebase realtime database.It shows me no error neither my app crashes but my queries don't work.I am trying to add some queries on to my database but my my recyclerview show data without any query attached.

[image: DataBase Structure]

code

```
    public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter mUserAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    String TAG = "MyTag";
    ValueEventListener mValueEventListener;

    public UsersFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();



        readUser();
        //RandomUsers();


        //query = .orderByChild("id").startAt(generateRandom()).limitToFirst(6);



        return view;
    }


    private void readUser() {

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");


        mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", "mainActivityListener called");
                    //mUsers.add(user);

                    if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }

                }
                mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);
                mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        reference.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
        Query query=reference.orderByChild("First").equalTo("Arjun");
        query.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);




    }
}
```

Comment: what is the query u want to do?

Comment: have u checked dataSnapshot has some value by debugging?

Comment: @PeterHaddad First i want to show user  whose name is Arjun . i have used First key for name .

Comment: @ShubhamKamlapuri i do show all the users in my recyclerview

Comment: you are bringing whole data from firebase, so better filter it at your application end by username or some id.

Comment: what is this '  if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }' snippet is doing?

Comment: @ShubhamKamlapuri actually my whole app is a messaging app it just prevent user to himself in users tab where he can see all the other users who are registered on my app

Comment: ok got it, then if you are getting the whole list of the user, simply filter out the current user data from the list coming from firebase. what is the problem then?

Comment: if you have saved the user id in integer form, check for that id in the list and remove it.

Comment: simply remove this line ' reference.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);' from your code, it is overriding two times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two `valueeventlistener`:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
Query query=reference.orderByChild("First").equalTo("Arjun");
query.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
```

If you want to filter according to the value of the `First` attribute, then just do the following:

```
Query query=reference.orderByChild("First").equalTo("Arjun");
query.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
```